# How to silently log stuff not to interfere with the normal development until I need it

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

I currently have a very weird and occasional bug that happens every 100-200 uses.

I really can't reproduce it and I'm not interested in spending too much time fixing it since it is not high priority but I would still like to fix it.

In order to do so, I would actually need to have 30 or so console.log all over the place, that may help.

The problem is that those console.logs are pretty annoying for the normal development process and completely clog my console, this is a pretty high prize to pay in order to have a possibility to know a little bit more about the issue whenever this weird bug occurs.

I am wondering what would be the best way to do so? To summarize I need to have "silent" console.log that are not on my way but will be there when the bug occurs again.

I've given it some though and I have two alternatives but I'm not sure I'm too happy with any of them:

1. Make an array to which I will push the relevant information and then print it out from the console when the error occurs.
2. Make a text file log that writes down the relevant information and read through it when the error occurs.

Am I missing something better? which approach would you use either of these two or a different one that I may be missing.

EDIT: Please not that this behavior doesn't produce any errors, just a weird ui behavior.

Comment: "I'm not sure I'm too happy with any of them" Why not? Those seem perfectly legitimate to me.

Comment: `console.debug` `console.trace` `console.info`?

Comment: @PaulDraper nothing particularly wrong. I just think they are a little bit primitive and I might be missing something more neat. (In fact take a look at this answer, this is the kind of thing I though I might be missing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22793132/463065)

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher not a bad suggestion, but in chrome you cant filter out selectively, it's all or one. So that would be that I would have to be constantly switching between debug and errors all again have them all together. I believe FF let's you filter out selectively.

Comment: BTW, not sure who down voted the question, but I don't see how it's not a valid SO question. IMHO it's well written and well researched, I'm even providing two possible solutions. I realize it's not your typical SO question but I don't think it's not a valid one, I would like to hear your opinion nonetheless.

Comment: @Trufa - Chrome lets you filter selectively.  On the Chrome console there is a little circle with a line through it to clear the console. Next to that is something which kind of looks like a sideways speaker.  Click on that and you can access the console filters.  Just for reference, the `Network` tab has a similar filter.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I was definitely aware of the filters, I use them all the time but I had never figured out that by pressing control and click you can select some of them. This makes your answer a good possibility, if you're interested please post it as an answer, I think it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the array one like this

```
function silentConsole () {
    this.data = [];
}
silentConsole.prototype.log = function(input) {
    this.data.push(input);
};
silentConsole.prototype.print = function() {
    this.data.forEach(function(line){
        console.log("### " + line);
    });
};

var sConsole = new silentConsole();
sConsole.log("something");
sConsole.print(); // "### something" in console
```

Comment: This is a very nice piece of code. Simple, clean, does what you need. If the bug doesn't take the program down with it, this is a good solution. Otherwise, you lose the information before you have a chance to examine the debug output.

Comment: @Floris I forgot to mention that the bug doesn't cause any error, didn't thought it was relevant until you mentioned it. I've edited my question, thank for bringing it up.

Comment: @Timo this is a sweet piece of code, I think I'm going to go this, I'll just wait for some other answers, but thanks a lot because it looks great!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `grouping` option - see https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consolegroupobject_object

This allows you to put a bunch of related debug statements together but have them "collapsed" - this seems to be a clean approach to the problem you are describing.

Comment: Is there a way to define a group when logging? It seemed to me that a group was started, then any logging occurs under that group, then a group is ended. That wouldn't really help random logs firing at different times/locations.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for (without knowing). I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @rgthree you're right this is kind of annoying and for now stopping me from using this solution as is.

Answer (score 1):

**Posting as an answer per comments**

You can use one of the other `console` logs, such as `console.debug` or `console.info`.

Chrome and Firefox let you selectively filter the console by the log type and some loggers even allow you to filter the log by text or regular expression.

*Chrome specific answer*

In chrome you can click the funnel and then click or control click to group whichever options you wish to see:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! BTW, that is a [funnel](https://www.google.com/search?q=funnel&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=two7U-jQMYnN7AbIw4CIAg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=992) not a sideways speaker :)

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea what that weird symbol was supposed to be.  Worst thing they ever did to computer `UI`s was replacing useful words with mystery symbols.

Comment: It's a kind of [Skeuomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph), sometimes a image is worth a thousand words though, but I agree that some ui text elements are not easily replaceable by images logos. Some are, think of the x to close, imagine if you had to write close.